# SSAS Dimension Grouping

Tags: ssas

I am having problem trying to group my dimension by the year using SSAS. This is the first time for me deploying a cube. Is there any way so that I can simply group the year rather than seeing multiple lines of the same year (please see the attached image)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the `KeyColumn` property of the attribute `GL Year`, if the value of the Key is equal, they'd be automatically grouped. What you see in the list is the `NameColumn` property.

More info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174919(v=sql.90).aspx) and on [MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3271/sql-server-analysis-server-ssas-keycolumn-vs-namecolumn-vs-valuecolumn/).

Update:

For `KeyColumns` property, MSDN states:

> Contains the column or columns that represent the key for the attribute, which is the column in the underlying relational table in the data source view to which the attribute is bound.

This means whenever the value of the column(s) specified in this property are equal in the underlying table for any number of rows, SSAS will treat all these rows as one [`Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216769%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

In your example, say if you have a column `GLYear` in your relational table and in `KeyColumns` property you have specified the same column, the resultant list in your screenshot will have a single value for each year. Hence, all rows with value `2015` will be combined together to form a single member in that list.

Comment: Sorry could you please provide more details? I didn't quite get what you mean by "if the value of the Key is equal"?

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. However, it still hasn't resolved this. I do have GLYear listed as the key column (and the only key column) but it has not changed the aggregation and still showing multiple lines of the same year(s)

Comment: Also check what is its `NameColumn` property. If it is not same as `GLYear`, it is displaying some other column to show incorrect results.

Comment: can you show the underlying data of General ledge table inc the year column.